# Please provide me explanation for the Slider directive

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, angularjs-directive

I am trying to understand the Slider directive [provided here](http://jsfiddle.net/PRg5h/1/).

```
myApp.directive('slider', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
          scope: {
              ngModel: '='
          },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

          console.log(scope.ngModel);

          return $(elem).slider({
            range: "min",
            animate: true,
            value: scope.ngModel,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
              return scope.$apply(function(){
                scope.ngModel = ui.value;
              });
            }
          });
        }
      };
    });
```

Like purpose of `ngmodel, range, animate, value:scope.ngModel` etc. I have read some article about the same from [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/directives-in-angularjs-simplified-with-examples-part-1/) but this seems to be a little complicated for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a  typical `isolated scope` directive configuration that is using a jQuery plugin .

`scope.ngModel` is passed in to the directive through the matching attribute `ng-model` in the html.

The `'='` makes it a 2 way binding to it's parent.

As for the slider it is a jQuery UI slider and the options like `animate` and `range` etc are documented in their API

`$apply()` is used whenever events outside of angular context are used to modify scope. Angular needs to be told to run a digest to update the view